# How to include a .bmp image in XeTex using plain TeX source file

Tags: graphics, xetex, plain-tex, jpeg, bitmap

Using XeTeX, I would like to insert a bitmap image file which is in `.bmp` format, or alternatively, the same image in a `.jpg` format. I am using plain TeX, not LaTeX.

Using PCTeX version 6,

```
\special{bmp:nhsealBW.bmp x=1in y=1in}
```

puts the `.bmp` image at the current location.

With pdfTeX I was using a set of pdfTeX special commands which are not available in XeTeX:

```
\newbox\stateseal

\setbox\stateseal\hbox{\pdfximage height 1in width 1in {nhsealbw.jpg}
\pdfrefximage\pdflastximage}
```

Puts the `.jpg` image into the box and

```
\copy\stateseal
```

inserts it at the current location.

How do I do that in XeTeX?

Comment: Please use 4 spaces to indent code blocks and back ticks for inline code. For blocks, you can highlight them and then click the `{}` button or ctrl+k.

Comment: Have you looked at PGF/TikZ? Although it recommends `graphicx` where that's an option (obviously not here), it also have image inclusion capabilities. You just have to declare the image first, if I remember rightly.

Comment: What would that look like in plain TeX source file? And where does PGF/TikZ come from? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean where does it come from? It is part of all standard TeX distributions, like other packages.

Comment: Ok, but what would the plain TeX source code to declare the image and use it look like?

Comment: Why don't you look in the documentation? It pretty consistently provides syntax for plain, LaTeX and ConTeXt.

Comment: See section 105 of the manual. Actually, it won't help as you are using XeTeX. If pdfTeX is an option, you can use PGF image declaration and inclusion with plain TeX. Otherwise, it only works with the LaTeX format, apparently.

Comment: I have to use XeTeX. So my original question remains.

Comment: I still recommend reading section 105 because I suspect that the reason you are having trouble is closely connected with the reason PGF image inclusion depends on LaTeX for all engines except pdfTeX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to:

1. Convert image_01.bmp to image_01.eps [the imagemagik suite will do this.
2. Use the following PSTRICKS command
   \centerline{\epsfysize = 5.0truecm\epsfbox{image_01.eps}}

[see do-it-yourself-tex on CTAN for the import PSTRICKS commands, etc]

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try. Is imagemagik suite on any TL distributions or do I get it from imagemagick.org?

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to use the XeTeX primitives to query the image size and specify the image inclusion to xdvipdfmx driver, but even in plain TeX using system-specific `\special` is painful and makes switching tex engines or drivers more complicated than need be.

You can use the same driver independent image inclusion macros as latex, which are already set up to do the right thing for bmp files with xetex.

[image]

from the plain xetex file

```
\input graphicx


a work of art:


\includegraphics{man.bmp}


\bye
```

where `man.bmp` is

[image]

Comment: But is it a your picture with your hands:-)? +1.

Comment: I need to query the image size so I can position the image without trial & error. Using Xetex primitives, can you demonstrate with your example please?  Thank you.

Comment: @GAS4 easiest is to use `\box0\hbox{\includegraphics{man}}` then use `\ht0` and `\wd0` for the height and width. and finally `\box0` to use the image

Comment: @GAS4 I guess you figured it out, but for any future readers, my comment above should start `\setbox0` not `\box0`

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but it should be pointed out that you can just do

```
\XeTeXpicfile <filename> [scaled <int> width <dimen> height <dimen>]
```

with XeTeX.

More options can be found in [the reference document](https://ctan.org/pkg/xetexref).

Answer (score 0):

graphviz is available for many platforms (in particular it is on
most LINUX distributions); see:
https://graphviz.org/download/
it may already be there; you want the "convert" command: You can test via:

```
convert picture.bmp picture.eps
```

There are probably other convertors for your system; probably based on 
graphviz.

Comment: Actually `convert` does not belong to Graphviz, but to ImageMagick, which is a dependency of Graphviz (see `apt-cache rdepends graphviz`) and is installed too.

Comment: Sorry about writing "graphviz" instead of "imagemagick"; thank you  Phelype for correcting me. I had been using the former all day and I inadvertently typed "graphviz". The best place for determining where to obtain a version of imagemagick for your system is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick