# How to insert a image in plain TeX using no helping library?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, plain-tex, ps

How could I insert a image in plain TeX, having a good control over its positions and scale, using no additional library (supposedly, a lot of ps commands as argument of \special)? I am intend to work with pdftex and using a png file. No problem in using tex -> dvips -> ps2pdf.

Thanks in advance.

**PS:** I want to understand in a low level how TeX operates for this kind of problem.

Comment: check the pdftex documentation, `texdoc pdftex-a`, it describes the low-level commands. Or study the latex graphicx driver pdftex.def.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63789/82917 (in particular Henri Menke's answer).

Comment: Campa, tex.stackexchange.com/q/63789/82917 - this question is different from mine.

Comment: Ulrike - good suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: I never claimed it was the same question. I pointed out that that one answer given there might be useful in your case.

Comment: Plain TeX has no graphics capability whatsoever.  Instead one would use \special{...} to pass image files directly to the DVI where hopefully the viewer would convert and display them.

Comment: The `insbox` plain TeX macros package defines `\InsertBoxL, \InsertBoxR` and `\InsertBoxC` commands.

Comment: @JohnKormylo *TeX* does not have any graphics capability whatsoever; PDFTeX does. My guess is that the OP still cannot tell the difference between an engine and a format.

Comment: so, my guess is that @campa's comment is right on the spot: the Plain format is oblivious to graphics inclusion: you need either a DVI driver or a suitable engine to do the job. Henri Menke's answer gives the basic clues to include graphics (jpg, png) with the PDFTeX engine; and if the OP wants to go the DVI way, they have to check the manual for dvipdf[m[x]], because dvips cannot handle png/jpg.

Comment: David Carlisle gives a simple example in his answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/525257/52679)

Comment: also related (with example code for XeTeX): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/307370/52679

Comment: You could look into `bm2font`. Apparently it converts bitmap images (like GIF, but I don't think it works with  PNG so you'd have to convert your PNG to GIF first) to PK fonts which can then be used by plain TeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Plain format does not provide any graphics facilities; those are provided by the engine or the DVI driver.

Since you mention that you mean to use PDFTeX, I suggest to you to grab the manual and read sections 7.9 and 8. The same approach should work, to the best of my knowledge, with LuaTeX, though the engine is far bigger and more complex. XeTeX also supports different graphics formats; read section 6 of the XeTeX Reference Guide.

Since `dvips` does not support png/jpg graphics, the way to include graphics in those formats via DVI files is by using the `dvipdf[m[x]]` driver; see section 8 of the manual for further details.

If, however, you *still* want to mess with including PostScript files or instructions *directly*, via `\special`s, and then process them with `dvips`, read sections 5.1 and 5.3 of the `dvips` manual.

The [graphics-pln](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphics-pln) package extends the Plain format to support LaTeX style graphics inclusion via [miniltx](https://ctan.org/pkg/miniltx); you may learn something by reading the source code.

Answer (score 3):

OPmac are macros for plain TeX, they provide a macro `\inspic` which inserts the graphics using `\pdfximage` and `\pdfrefximage` primitives. You can use OPmac macros or read the implementation of the `\inspic` macro and inspire. The implemetation is only four lines of code (unlike 200 lines of graphicx). OPTeX is LuaTeX+PlainTeX+OPmac, the `\inspic` macro including its implementation is documented at page 136 of the OpTeX manual.

Comment: `\inspic` works in XeTeX too, see opmac-xetex.tex. IMHO, it is better to do simple things with single engine (like OpTeX) than solve problems much more complicated way for various engines or output devices. Of course, there is no standard way to deal graphics in TeX, but if we select one engine, we can do very straightforward macros.

Comment: When user use `\input opmac` and `\inspic` then `\inspic` works in pdfTeX with PDF output, luaTeX and XeTeX. What primitives are used is typically not important for users. So, the notice "`\inspic` is supported only in PDFTeX" is at least inaccurate.

Comment: Yes, this specific "user" wants primitive solution. I give the answer: you can see the primitive solution from opmac.tex macro file, see four related lines here. Of course, if somebody needs a general solution for all back-ends, then there is no simple four lines, but user needs to create many branches of his macros. But user asks for simplicity, which is not to take account all backends nor reading and inspiring from graphics.sty (600 lines of code plus reads trig.sty: 100 lines plus graphics.cfg: 60 lines plus pdftex.def: 680 lines) nor graphicsx.sty (200 lines plus the same input files).

Comment: The "general case" is impossible because there is no standard of including graphics in TeX. Imagine various `\specials` for HP, Inkjet languages, more more languages of various historical devices, PostScript, dvi-to-something drivers etc., etc. My answer selects one most typically used backend and illustrates that things can be simple.

Comment: If you fear that I have "hatred for LaTeX" then your fearings are unfounded. But this is off topic, OP didn't asked for LaTeX solution and I show non-LaTeX solution. May be, your fearing blinds you more often than not... :).