# Plain TeX Image Workaround For Lab Manuals

Tags: graphics, overleaf, plain-tex, includegraphics, update

I am working on importing physics lab manuals that were written in TeX to Overleaf so that our faculty can collaborate and update the content.

Everything is working flawlessly, except for inserting images. The images were added using the commands `\figure\midfigure` and `\figure\topfigure` originally in Tex, but Overleaf is not rendering the .eps images (regardless of compiler and latexmkrc settings).

The definitions I've found for \figure and \midfigure are as follows:

```
\def\figure#1,#2x#3.{\par\vbox to#2bp{\vss
    \special{psfile="figures/#1" voffset=0 hoffset=#3 vscale=100 hscale=100}}}
```

```
\def\figure#1"#2" #3 to #4, #5.{\global\advance\fignum by1 #1
    \oldpicheight=#3bp
    \picheight=#4
    \scaling=\picheight
    \multiply\scaling by100
    \divide\scaling by\oldpicheight
    \vbox to#4{\vss\special{psfile="../figures/#2" voffset=0 hoffset=#5 hscale=\number\scaling vscale=\number\scaling\ }}
    \ifx\relax\thecaption\else{\narrower\narrower\noindent\thecaption\par}\fi
    \endinsert
    \global\let\thecaption=\relax}

% Syntax: \topfig"name.jpg" <height>[in pixels] to <height>[on page], <hoffset> "caption"
```

```
\def\topfig{\figure\topinsert} % \topfig "filename" {old height in points} to {new height}, {hoffset}.
\def\midfig{\figure\midinsert}
\def\pagefig{\figure\pageinsert}
```

*The workaround I have found is using LaTeX packages via:*

`\input miniltx.tex`
`\input graphicx.sty`

And by replacing the image code with something like this:

`\includegraphics[height=4.5in,width=5.5in]{figures/Titlepicture.eps}`

**All of pictures are now showing, but unfortunately, some of these pictures need a horizontal offset and I can't figure out how to add that. I tried to incorporate the figure environment like in this tutorial (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Inserting_Images) but had no luck. The new code is working great except for not being able to add a horizontal offset. I tried variations of `\centerline` and `\centering` with no success. Thank you!**

On Overleaf, I'm using the LaTex compiler with TeX live version 2020 (legacy). The original code says it was written in XeTex. Here is my latexmkrc file:

```
#$latex = 'tex %O %S'; # to use Knuth's original TeX engine
#$latex = 'pdftex %O %S'; # to use the pdfTeX engine
#$latex = 'luatex %O %S'; # to use the LuaTeX engine
$latex = 'xetex %O %S';  # to use the XeTeX engine
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We'll need to see your `latexmk` setup: the standard settings use pdfTeX, and `graphics` arranges to turn EPS files to PDF format automatically

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you for your reply, I've updated my post with that information

Comment: @LdBeth I should be able to convert them to PDF format. However, I tried inserting .pdf files into the original TeX code and nothing was rendered. What is the workaround? Thank you!

Comment: I’m not sure if your manual needs any XeTeX specific features or not. If it needs XeTeX then check this link out https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/307370/246082

Comment: @eagleradioastro as always you should provide an example. Overleaf has a full texlive so whatever plain tex macros you were using should work but as you have not shown any input, or what error you got, it is hard to help

Comment: you can use `\hbox{\hskip 2cm\includegraphics....}` to move the image

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry I do not use Overleaf that often so I misjudged. I have adapted my answer to prove a macro tested against XeTeX with Overleaf now.

Comment: Thank you @David Carlisle, using the syntax ```\hbox{\hskip ?cm\includegraphics[height=?cm]{exampleimage.eps}}``` solved the issue and is everything is working! The original code has manual offsets which I can now replicate and fully update the manuals. Much appreciated!

Comment: if you showed a small example document (you can use `example-image.eps`) that works on your local system someone would show how to use the same document on overleaf, if you just show fragments it is hard to help

Comment: @David Carlisle It seems that I'm missing some vertical spacing before and after the centered image. Is there a way to modify the ```\hbox{\hskip ?cm\includegraphics[height=?cm]{exampleimage.eps}}``` command to add vertical spacing above and below the image?

Comment: Not sure if it hleps, but there is a `plain` package   See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203703/conversion-of-tex-to-latex

Comment: `\vskip 3cm\hbox{...}\vskip 3cm` but you don't need any of that. You could use exactly the same macros as you use locally

Answer (score 0):

The first `\figure` definition is probably been override so it has no use.

The thing needs to be updated is the second `\figure`. Since there are some dependency not know I have not run test samples my self, but this macro should be compatible with the original one.

```
\def\figure#1"#2" #3 to #4, #5.{\global\advance\fignum by1 #1
    \oldpicheight=#3bp
    \picheight=#4
    \scaling=\picheight
    \divide\scaling by\oldpicheight
    \vbox to #4{\vss\leavevmode\kern#5pt\includegraphics[scale=\number\scaling]{../figures/#2}}
    \ifx\relax\thecaption\else{\narrower\narrower\noindent\thecaption\par}\fi
    \endinsert
    \global\let\thecaption=\relax}

% Syntax: \topfig"name.jpg" <height>[in pixels] to <height>[on page], <hoffset> "caption"
```

However if you want to get rid of the old macros, which I think you should do, you may reference my previous answer.

---

**Previous answer:**

It seems the manuals requires XeTeX to be compiled, and `\figure` seems to be a custom made macro.

You problem with the figures not horizontally align is because
`graphicx` itself does not middle align images. You can to that by
using `\centerline{#1}` which is essentially the same as something like `\hbox{\hfil#1\hfil}`.

My workaround would be redefine `\figure` to use `graphicx` package. I implemented the macro by purely guessing about the `\midfigure` means use plain TeX's `\midinsert` and `\topfigure` means use `\topinsert` and based on what I use to insert figures in pdfTeX. You may adapt the third argument if you don't need the caption, and maybe include `\includegraphics` inside the macro if not going to adjust size of pictures. The example below tested on Overleaf with XeTeX, although I didn't test agains EPS specifically but it should work.

latexmkrc:

```
$latex = 'xetex %O %S';
```

```
\input graphicx

\def\figure#1#2#3{%
\edef\instr{\string#1}
\edef\midfigstr{\string\midfigure}
\edef\topfigstr{\string\topfigure}
\ifx\instr\midfigstr
\midinsert
\else \ifx\instr\topfigstr
\topinsert
\else \errmessage{What is #1?} \fi\fi
\centerline{#2}\par
\centerline{#3}\endinsert}
This is good.
Text Text$\ldots$

\figure\midfigure{\includegraphics{a.png}}{Figure 1: this is an image.}

\vfil\eject %new page

This is good.
Text Text$\ldots$
\figure\topfigure{\includegraphics{a.png}}{Ok.}
\bye
```

First page (`\midfigure`)
[image: Frist page]
Second page (`\topfigure`)
[image: Second page]

Comment: When I try this, the project won't compile correctly and has numerous errors. Additionally, I tried using .jpg in the original code and these won't work either.

Comment: @eagleradioastro ok so I think the \figure macro you’ve mentioned is a custom made one, do you mind sharing its definition? If you cannot find it I have write a brief example later.

Comment: @eagleradioastro anyway I updated my answer to provide the work around, please see if this would work.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. If I understand correctly, there are two options (1) use centerline with ```\includegraphics``` to align horizontally, OR (2) rewrite the ```\figure``` macro to use graphicsx? For option 1, what is the correct syntax to use ```\centerline``` and apply a horizontal offset? I was unable to get centerline to work properly. Regarding option 2, I found the macro for \figure which I will update my post with.

Comment: @eagleradioastro `\smallskip\centerline{\includegraphics{a.png}}\smallskip` Something like this to make sure the figure is not mixed with content before or after. I would recommend update the macro which would make future changes easier to be made.

Comment: @eagleradioastro I have made a new macro that should work the same as the old one, since I know there are some unknown variables referenced I cannot test the macro myself, so let me know if there are some issues.